# Cards probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two players; the dealer and a player. The player is given three cards face down. The dealer turns over a 2 (let's say of hearts). Before the player turns any cards over, what is the probability that at least one of the player's cards is greater than the 2 (and of the same suit)?

Please help and can you provide your workings? Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify: when the dealer turns over a 2, is this not one of the cards dealt to the player (so the player still has three face down) cards? And is ace considered to be greater than the 2?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you provide your own ideas on this question? This allows other people to give better answers.

Comment: They are playing from a standard 52 cards and yes the 2 is taken from this deck so this cannot be one of the players cards. Ace is considered high, so in effect I need the probability that the player has a heart.

Comment: I thought at first the probability would be 12/51+12/50+12/49 but this doesn't work out. Thanks.

Comment: After the dealer has turned over the 2, does the player still have 3 cards, ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The dealer turns over his own card, the player still has three face down cards

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For "at least" type probabilities, it is best to use the idea of the "complement", which here means 1 - P(no hearts with player)

Hint 2: So the 3 cards with the player would come from 12 hearts and 39 "others". Find the probability that all 3 come from "others", and then find its complement.

Comment: Ok I think I have it: probability = 1-((39/51)(38/50)(37/49)). Is this right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right ! :)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome !